# Stop and restart rtsp stream in opencv for object detection

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, object-detection, rtsp

I am working on an object_detection API implemented in tensorflow 1.14 and opencv 4.1, where my task is to recognize personal protection equipment weard by workers at various construction site gates. We are using RTSP streams, where I am already using threading to minimize latency, but still some times the stream crashes.
So I decided to restart the whole python script every 'n' times of detection to prevent the whole thing to crash because of corrupted frames and so on, but tensorflow is very slow with the loading of inference graph and such for the first time (for me its ~20 seconds), which is unacceptable to wait for the workers to get inside the site at the gate.
So now I am considering to just stop and then restart JUST the RTSP stream with opencv, which constantly feeds with frames the inference machinery for executing object detection on them.

Now I have not found any helpful threads on this topic, so that is why I am writing it here.

The relevant part of my code is here:

```
from threading import Thread
import cv2, time
import numpy as np
import os
import six.moves.urllib as urllib
import sys
import tarfile
from threading import Thread
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.tensorrt as trt
import zipfile
from distutils.version import StrictVersion
from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from object_detection.utils import ops as utils_ops
import streamlit as st

######Initialize some important stuff###############
...
###### End of initialization###############

class VideoStreamWidget(object): # create threading



    detected_counter1 = 0
    detected_counter2 = 0
    PASS_score1 = 0
    NOPASS_score1 = 0
    PASS_score2 = 0
    NOPASS_score2 = 0
    scoresumCounter1=0
    scoresumCounter2=0
    PASS_score_tmp =0
    NOPASS_score_tmp=0
    detection_index = 0
    detboxesAreaTMP1 = [0,0,0,0]
    detboxesAreaTMP2 = [0,0,0,0]
    def __init__(self, src=rtsp_Url):
        # Create a VideoCapture object
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(src)

        # Start the thread to read frames from the video stream
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.update, args=())
        self.thread.daemon = True
        self.thread.start()
        self.counter = 0

    def update(self): # here the update of "raw" frames happen
        # Read the next frame from the stream in a different thread
        while True:
            if self.capture.isOpened():
                (self.status, self.frame) = self.capture.read()

    def show_frame(self): # here inference and post processing of images happen


if __name__ == '__main__':
    video_stream_widget = VideoStreamWidget(rtsp_Url)

    with detection_graph.as_default():
        with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.35))) as sess:
        # Get handles to input and output tensors
            ops = tf.get_default_graph().get_operations()
            all_tensor_names = {output.name for op in ops for output in op.outputs}
            tensor_dict = {}
            for key in ['num_detections', 'detection_boxes', 'detection_scores','detection_classes', 'detection_masks']:
                tensor_name = key + ':0'
                if tensor_name in all_tensor_names:
                    tensor_dict[key] = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name(tensor_name)
            resfresherCounter = 0
            while True:
# I think here it should be implemented somehow to close the stream and reopen it

                try:
                    video_stream_widget.show_frame() # here the objec tdetection happens
                except cv2.error as e:
                    print(e)
                    continue
```

My whole code is here:

https://pastebin.com/7qBFwwfy

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Nice story! But is there a question? If you are looking for code review, you can ask it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The question is, how can I restart just the RTSP stream inside opencv and not the whole application?